# Calendar - add a new calendar entry every time a new item is entered in a custom list

Tags: calendar

I would like to add a calendar event everytime a new entry is created in a custom list. Is this possible?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this.  Do you have a preferred method (Workflow or Script)?

Answer (score 3):

short answer: yes, this is possible

long answer: do you have *any* requirements on how to achieve this. SharePoint 2010 or 2007? anyway, the 3 methods that came up into my mind:

- custom sharepoint designer workflow
- create an eventhandler and programmatically add a calendar event
- a javascript solution (csom)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have been able to do this by using a workflow :).